# I have a old battery charge, which says its output is 6 - 12 Volt 4 Amps R.M.S. Does this mean the output is AC?

Tags: power-supply, power

The battery charger is an HC45 which I could not find any information online about. As stated in the question does the 4 Amps R.M.S mean the output is AC or is the peak of the input equal to 4 Amps?

Comment: Is R.M.S limited to AC?

Comment: @TonyM I do not have an oscilloscope. I might be able to use my multi meter however. Also there was no AC symbol.

Comment: Of course is not AC since the battery is DC, but it is probably pulsed voltage, half wave rectified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those older chargers are very simple — just a transformer and a rectifier, no filter. The output is pulsating rather than what we would consider "pure DC". Therefore, it makes a certain amount of sense to rate the output current in terms of its RMS value rather than its peak or average value — mainly because that's how the internal transformer is rated.

While the voltage pulses are half-sinewaves, the actual current pulses are narrower spikes whose actual shape depends on the state of charge (i.e., terminal voltage) of the battery. It is the RMS value of the current that determines how much stress is being put on the transformer and rectifier.